# How to present two series of timespan data in a chart?`Excel/PowerBI (Or other tool suggestions)

Tags: analysis, statistics

I want to plot two different datasets that are true/false in given periods/durations.
How can i do this in excel (or antoher tool). See picture for what i want to acvhice.

The data is two TimerSeries that are true (active) in a series of timespans/intervals.
I want to compare when they are active.

[image]

Maybe i'm thinking about this wrong, i assumed it would be very easy with some excel-chart to auto plot this :S What chart should i use? How to structure the data? How to add it to the Chart?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: So where to put it ?

Comment: @otk you may try https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: However your question currently lack an attempt and a reproducible dataset/example, so I think you might have to improve it a little before posting it again there.